# Spring Boot are there Swagger Annotation on Rest Controllers

Tags: rest, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

In Spring Boot are there Swagger annotations that I use on rest controller methods to describe the input and output mime types?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use "consumes" and "produces" annotation parameters for input and output Mime.

[MIME type in swagger](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/mime-types/)